# Single-cell RNA sequencing proper abbreviation

Tags: scrnaseq, terminology, nomenclature

I wonder which form of a single-cell RNA sequencing abbreviation is correct:

- > scRNA-seq
- > scRNA-Seq

In the same single-cell sequencing Wikipedia article, both forms appear.
There is also inconsistency among papers I've seen - some authors prefer the first form, others the second one.

If there's any reason behind the different form, I'd like to hear about it.